# how to exclude specific api from applying all the authorization of python middleware

Tags: python, django

Let suppose I Have a webhook that will request to my python server and I want to allow that request to process without applying any middleware authorization of python.

I don't want to make more costly process of request/response by processing all the requests in my custom middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate settings file for a different web server instance where it would use that settings file. You'd also likely need to create a separate `urls.py` so that you don't grant access to other views.